# Ошибка в codeception webdrvier

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, codeception

Содержание 'acceptance.suite.yml'. Пробовал еще порты :4444, :80, :8080 к url дописывать

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
    modules:
        enabled:
            - WebDriver
            - PhpBrowser
            - \Helper\Acceptance
    config:
          WebDriver:
                 url: 'http://localhost/'
                 browser: 'firefox'
                 delay: 10
          PhpBrowser:
                 url: 'http://localhost/'
```

Ошибка возникает и когда запущен phantomjs 2.0 (phantomjs --webdriver=4444, читал, что это распространенная ошибка) и с selenium 2.47.1 И когда запущен selenium и когда phantomjs, и когда не один не запущен.

При запуске такая ошибка

```
[Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException]                            
      JSON decoding of remote response failed.                                     
      Error code: 4                                                                
      The response: '<html><body>Connection to server <b>127.0.0.1</b> failed (Co  
      nnection actively refused by the server.)<P></body></html>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через Selenium с таким конфигом заработало

```
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver
        - PhpBrowser
        - \Helper\Acceptance
    config:
          WebDriver:
                 url: 'http://localhost/'
                 port: 4444
                 browser: 'firefox'
                 wait: 10
                 restart: true
                 capabilities:
                   unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'accept'
          PhpBrowser:
                      url: 'http://localhost/'
```